# UISlider Doesn't Receive Touch At Right End

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uislider

I've got a UISlider in my main view, but it doesn't receive touches at the right end. I thought it could be a pesky view covering it, but it definitely isn't. Has anyone got any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your `UISlider` fell out of bounds of the superview. Try to set background of `UISlider` superview to some color and check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Its in your control to set the height and width of UISlider, using CGRectMake... and its touch sensitive till the given width.. i think u would have missed writing the below option...

```
silder_Obj.userInteractionEnable = YES;
```

Just try it out.. it had worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that in my case, the issue occurred when the right/left border of the UISlider matched its superview's corresponding border. Making the superview wider so that there would be 5.0-10.0 distance between their borders solved the issue for me.